# Generate and store a unique id in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, nsuserdefaults, uuid

I am looking at transitioning an app of mine from standard iOS Objective C to C# using MonoTouch.

In my Objective C code I am generating a unique identifier and saving it to NSUserDefaults to validate and check on subsequent logins.  Here is the method that I am using for that:

```
- (NSString *) localUuid {
        NSString * ident = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:UUID];
        if(!ident){
            CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
            CFStringRef uuidStringRef = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuidRef);
            CFRelease(uuidRef);
            ident = [NSString stringWithString:(__bridge_transfer NSString *)uuidStringRef];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:ident forKey:UUID];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
        return ident;

    }
```

I am having problems getting something similar to work in C# with MonoTouch though.

I haven't found a version of the CFUUID_*_* methods available with Mono.
Also, while there appears to be a NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetValueForKey method, there isn't a straightforward GetValueForKey method.

Does anyone more experienced with Monotouch know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`CFUUID` is not bound because it's easier to use .NET `System.Guid` to achieve the same. E.g.

```
var uuid = Guid.NewGuid ();
string s = uuid.ToString (); // if a string is preferred
```

> Also, while there appears to be a NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetValueForKey method, there isn't a straightforward GetValueForKey method.

There are safely type methods to do the same, e.g.:

```
NSUserDefaults settings = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
settings.SetString (s, "key");
```

Comment: Thanks, the Guid part works great, so I will accept this as the answer. But I was having problems getting the string from the settings, not setting them.

Comment: @cain from memory doing `settings ["key"]` should return you an `NSString` on which you can call `.ToString()` to get a C# string.

Comment: from looking (instead of memory) you'll be better off using `setting.StringForKey ("key")`.